# mongoose: how to return documents not Cursor with .find()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
await mongoose.connection.db.collection('ways').find({}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This results

```
Cursor {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _eventsCount: 36,
    _maxListeners: Infinity,

  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

I have my data there. When I do `.findOne({})`, it returns the value correctly. However, I am trying to return all the values. I also tried with `.toArray()` and didn't really work. It returns nothing but undefined or this Cursor. What should I change in order to get the Documents not the Cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `lean()` function of [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

`let result = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('ways').find({}).lean()`

Answer (score 2):

you can't using await with callback function together

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('ways').find({}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

or

```
let result = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('ways').find({})
```

Comment: Actually I think `await .find()` returns a query and still needs to be `.exec()` executed : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find - or is using `collection('ways')` somehow different to using Models ?

Comment: no, it's not necessary when you using `await`, check the https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: `mongoose.connection.db.collection('ways').find({}, (err, result) => {
  console.log(result);
  res.send('hmm');
 });` changed to this but still it returns Cursor :/